# Enable user to change sorting order, but form data stops after first loop

Tags: php

I have some form data to process, but I fear I'm not tackling the problem from the right angle. Basically I want to give the user the ability to change the order in which categories are displayed. Categories are ordered by a column called Sort, which is an auto increment number.

The form grabs data from the database and displays the list of categories along with the sort number, which the user can change.

**FORM**

```
<form autocomplete="off" class="fancy_form" method="POST" action="process_sort_categories.php">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>SORT CATEGORIES</legend>
        <?php

            $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM category ORDER BY sort");

            try
            {
                $stmt->execute();
            }
            catch(PDOExecption $e)
            {
                echo error_handle($e);
            }

            echo '<div id="sort"><table>';

            while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            {
                echo '<tr><td>' . $row['title'];
                echo '<td><input type="text" name="' . $row['id'] . '" value="' . $row['sort'] . '""></td></tr>';
            }

            echo '</div></table>';

        ?>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Re-Order">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

If I just echo out the post data, it loops through fine, but as soon as I try updating the data, it stops after the first loop.

**PROCESS THE FORM**

```
require 'assets.php';

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM category ORDER BY id");

try
{
    $stmt->execute();
}
catch(PDOExecption $e)
{
    echo error_handle($e);
}

while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{

    $id = $row['id'];
    $sort = $_POST[$id];

    //echo $row['title'];
    //echo $sort . '<br>';

    $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE category SET sort = :sort WHERE id = :id");
    $stmt->bindParam(':sort', $sort, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    try
    {
        $stmt->execute();
    }
    catch(PDOExecption $e)
    {
        echo error_handle($e);
    }

}

$_SESSION['success'] = "Category Sorted Successfully";
header('Location: sort_categories.php');
```

I get the feeling I'm approaching this wrong, or a little hacky. Any help or advice would be appreciated greatly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you can instead use a grouping array for your form:

```
name="ids[<?php echo $row['$id']; ?>]"
```

Then loop (foreach) the `$ids = $_POST['ids'];` the keys are the ID and the sort values are the VALUES

Form:

```
echo '<div id="sort"><table>';
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<tr><td>' . $row['title'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td><input type="text" name="ids[' . $row['id'] . ']" value="' . $row['sort'] . '"" /></td></tr>';
}
echo '</div></table>';
```

PHP Process (process_sort_categories.php):

```
$ids = $_POST['ids'];
foreach($ids as $id => $sort) {
    try {
        $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE category SET sort = :sort WHERE id = :id");
        $stmt->bindParam(':sort', $sort, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
    catch(PDOExecption $e) {
        echo error_handle($e);
    }

}
```

Comment: That makes much more sense. Thank you for your help.